# Not able to install ubuntu 20.04 in my ‎HP Pavilion Gaming TG01-2008in Desktop PC

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, hp

My pc has 11th Gen Intel Core i5-11400F Hexa-core processor and has NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 Ti ( 8GB ) graphics GPU.

I made bootable pendrive from other linux machine using Rufus. Secure boot is off and there is no option for legacy boot in bios.
When I boot from pen drive ubuntu logo and loading logo comes and nothing happened after that(waited for 1 hour).

Please help if you know how to solve this problem.

Comment: 1. Ubuntu 20.04 precedes your hardware. I don't see a point in using it instead of the current 22.04. 2. You may need to select the "safe graphics" option and then, during the OS installation select the option to install 3rd party drivers in order to automatically install the proprietary Nvidia drivers. 3. As usual, even before installing make sure to update UEFI and, if applicable, SSDs' firmware.

Comment: How to install 3rd party drivers during installation?

Comment: At some point during thew installation that will be a selectable option. The same option was already present in 20.04 so if you missed it you were paying attention.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)